# Missing Create List from excel option

Tags: custom-list, modern-experience, excel, 2019, import

We have SharePoint Server 2019 version deployed, we moved from SharePoint Online to On-Premises version to satisfy Government regulations.

Here, I am trying to create a list following the guide from Microsoft:

[Create a list based on spreadsheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-list-based-on-a-spreadsheet-380cfeb5-6e14-438e-988a-c2b9bea574fa#ID0ELF=Modern)

However, in my version, this option is missing. Can you please help?
Add New List option:

[image: Add New List option]

Option only to manually create list:

[image: Option only to manually create list]

Custom list created like:

[image]

Are we missing anything in the installation?

Comment: Do you see "Create a list" popup wizard where you can select the list template or it just shows the panel like in 2nd image you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SharePoint 2019, follow below steps:

1. From SP site, select **Settings** icon, and then select **Add an app** (or go to URL like `<siteUrl>/_layouts/15/addanapp.aspx`).
2. In the **Find an app** field, enter spreadsheet, and then select the search icon

   [image]
3. In the search results page, select **Import Spreadsheet**.

   [image]

**Source**: [Create a list based on a spreadsheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-list-based-on-a-spreadsheet-380cfeb5-6e14-438e-988a-c2b9bea574fa#ID0ELF=Classic)

Answer (score 0):

The app shown won't work - it uses the ActiveX control that used to be the method for importing Excel files, and with Internet Explorer being removed, there's no way for it to launch.